# How can I get a Django Gunicorn project served up?

Tags: firewall, django, gunicorn

I have a Django project that was working on a development server and I am trying to move it to an Ubuntu production server. I've started, with apparent success, a "python manage.py run_gunicorn 0.0.0.0:8000", but my attempts to connect to it via a regular browser pointed to http://JonathansCorner.com:8000/ are timing out. (When I manually run "telnet localhost 8000", and give a GET request, it prints out appropriate HTML.) UFW is disabled.

What can I do to get Gunicorn available on port 80 from outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have three things for you to consider:

First, regarding your firewall, looks like you *do* have a firewall of some sort going on, as port 8000 is "filtered":

```
~ nmap jonathanscorner.com -p 8000

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-01-14 09:53 CST
Nmap scan report for jonathanscorner.com (54.218.143.2)
Host is up (0.10s latency).
rDNS record for 54.218.143.2: ec2-54-218-143-2.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8000/tcp filtered http-alt
```

Second, it looks like this is running on EC2? That being the case, you'll need to modify your security group to allow this traffic.

Third, it is typically not a great idea to have gunicorn exposed directly. Have gunicorn listen on `localhost:8000` (as you are), and then use a proper web server to proxy requests to gunicorn.

For instance, install nginx, and have **it** listen on port 80 and then proxy requests through to gunicorn on `localhost:8000`.